# Tengo un problema con mi carrusel en Javascript

Tags: javascript

El problema es que que el contador del carrusel pasa directamente de 1 a -1 sin pasar por 0 cuando me muevo hacia la izquierda. Esto impide que se agregaran las tarjetas correctamente y causa un comportamiento no deseado en el carrusel.

Funcionamiento del código:

Inicialización del carrusel:

Al cargar la página, se inicializa el carrusel estableciendo las variables de estado y agregando event listeners a los botones de movimiento.
Función moveCarrusel:

Esta función se activa cuando el usuario hace clic en uno de los botones de movimiento del carrusel.
Verifica si el carrusel está en medio de una transición. Si lo está, la función se detiene para evitar transiciones no deseadas.
Calcula el valor actual de transformación del carrusel y establece una transición para suavizar el movimiento.
Incrementa o decrementa el contador de tarjetas según la dirección de movimiento especificada.
Calcula la nueva transformación del carrusel basándose en el cambio en el contador y aplica esta transformación al carrusel.
Función reorderCard:

Esta función se activa al finalizar una transición en el carrusel.
Verifica si es la primera vez que se ejecuta la función después de la inicialización.
Si es la primera vez, inicializa el contador y establece el estado inicial del carrusel.
Si el contador llega a 1, lo ajusta para volver al estado inicial y evita que el carrusel se mueva a -1 directamente.
Reordena las tarjetas cuando el contador alcanza los límites superior o inferior del carrusel.
Event Listeners:

Los botones de movimiento del carrusel tienen event listeners que llaman a la función moveCarrusel con la dirección correspondiente cuando se hace clic en ellos.
El contenedor del carrusel también tiene un event listener para detectar el final de la transición, que activa la función reorderCard para reordenar las tarjetas según sea necesario.

```
const controlCarrusel = (id, containerId) => {
    // Obtener referencias a los elementos relevantes del carrusel
    const container = document.getElementById(containerId);
    const btn_left = document.getElementById(`btn_left${id}`);
    const btn_right = document.getElementById(`btn_right${id}`);
    const rootStyles = document.documentElement.style;

    // Obtener todas las tarjetas del carrusel
    let cardElements = document.querySelectorAll(`#${containerId} .cards`);

    // Variables de estado del carrusel
    let isInTransition = false;
    let cardCounter = 0;
    let initialized = true;

    // Constantes para las direcciones de movimiento
    const DIRECTION = {
        Left: "LEFT",
        Right: "RIGHT"
    }

    // Función para obtener el valor de transformación actual
    const getTransformValue = () => Number(rootStyles.getPropertyValue('--card-transform').replace("px", ""));

    // Función para reordenar las tarjetas después de la transición
    const reorderCard = () => {
        const transformValue = getTransformValue();
        rootStyles.setProperty("--transition", "none");

        // Si es la primera vez, inicializar el contador y salir
        if (initialized) {
            initialized = false;
            cardCounter = 1;
            isInTransition = false;
            return;
        }

        // Si el contador llega a 1, volver al estado inicial
        if (cardCounter === 1) {
            cardCounter--;
            isInTransition = false;
            return;
        }

        // Reordenar las tarjetas cuando llega al límite superior o inferior
        if (cardCounter === cardElements.length - 4) {
            container.appendChild(container.firstElementChild);
            rootStyles.setProperty('--card-transform', `${transformValue + cardElements[cardCounter].scrollWidth}px`);
            cardCounter--;
        } else if (cardCounter === 0) {
            container.prepend(container.lastElementChild);
            rootStyles.setProperty('--card-transform', `${transformValue - cardElements[cardCounter].scrollWidth}px`);
            cardCounter++;
        }

        isInTransition = false;
    };

    // Función para mover el carrusel hacia la izquierda o hacia la derecha
    const moveCarrusel = (direction) => {
        if (isInTransition) return;
        const transformValue = getTransformValue();
        rootStyles.setProperty('--transition', 'transform 0.3s');
        isInTransition = true;

        // Incrementar o decrementar el contador según la dirección
        if (direction === DIRECTION.Right) {
            cardCounter++;
        } else if (direction === DIRECTION.Left) {
            cardCounter--;
        }

        // Calcular la nueva transformación y aplicarla al carrusel
        rootStyles.setProperty('--card-transform', `${transformValue + (direction === DIRECTION.Left ? 1 : -1) * cardElements[0].scrollWidth}px`);
    }

    // Agregar event listeners para los botones de movimiento
    btn_left.addEventListener("click", () => { moveCarrusel(DIRECTION.Left) });
    btn_right.addEventListener("click", () => { moveCarrusel(DIRECTION.Right) });

    // Agregar event listener para detectar el fin de la transición y reordenar las tarjetas
    container.addEventListener("transitionend", reorderCard);

    // Llamar a reorderCard al inicio para establecer el estado inicial del carrusel
    reorderCard();

    // Establecer isInTransition a false al inicio para evitar transiciones no deseadas
    isInTransition = false;
}

// Exportar la función controlCarrusel para su uso fuera de este módulo
module.exports = {
    controlCarrusel
}
```

Comment: De ser posible, agrega un _snippet_ (con el botón `<>`) para poder reproducir el problema en la pregunta misma.